# is it perfectly ok to return a naked pointer to a unique_ptr from a class

Tags: c++

Is it ok to do the following? Obviously the caller is not prevented from deleting the naked pointer. Should I use shared_ptr and return a shared_ptr? It seems too heavy for this.

```
class A
{
   B* GetB() { return pointer.get(); }
private:
   unique_ptr<B> pointer;
};
```

Comment: Clearly, you no longer possess a unique pointer, as you intend for multiples to coexist. I would start by questioning my assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it should work fine as it is, making it clear in the documentation that such pointer is not intended to be `delete`d.

<s>Still, I would probably return a reference: in that case it's implicit that the caller mustn't `delete` anything.</s>

```
class A
{
   B & GetB() { return *(pointer.get()); }
private:
   unique_ptr<B> pointer;
};
```

***Edit*** it turns out that the pointer can be `NULL`; in such case, the reference must be avoided.

You *could* create some kind of smart-dumb `do_not_delete_me_ptr` class that just encapsulates the pointer and make extra clear that you must not delete it, but I think this too is overkill. ;)

Comment: the issue is the object can be null

Comment: @Sriram: well, then the reference is definitely out of choice, since dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (even to create a reference) is UB. I'd go with the naked pointer+doc warning, then, using `shared_ptr` for this stuff is *way* overkill.

Answer (score 0):

From the boost docs on [`unique_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html):

> A unique_ptr is not CopyConstructible, nor CopyAssignable, however it is MoveConstructible and Move-Assignable.

You can't return the `unique_ptr` itself anyways (because you're keeping a copy as a member).

If the object is guaranteed to be allocated (i.e. the pointer is never null), I would return a reference.

Comment: He's not returning a `unique_ptr`, he's returning the pointer that the `unique_ptr` is encapsulating.

Comment: Sorry, mis-phrased my answer.  This should be fixed.